# decompress a .Z file in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How to decompress a .Z file in Azure Data Factory while pulling the file from source (SFTP) to ADLS. I've tried all the availabe options in Dataset but it's not working. I'm able to decompress a zip file but not able to do for .Z file.

Error - message":

> "Failure happened on 'Sink' side.
>   ErrorCode=UserErrorUnzipInvalidFile,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The
>   file 'nz.drstores.cdp.csv.Z' is not a valid Zip file with Deflate
>   compression
>   method.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.IO.InvalidDataException,Message=End
>   of Central Directory record could not be
>   found.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,

Comment: Use the code view for Error message. Error message inside the pair of ``` 3 back tick or select the error message and use the code button on top of the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADF deflate compression only supports below format of compress files which is stated in the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-binary#dataset-properties) clearly:

[image]

So no built-in feature in ADF,you may need to convert .Z file into supported format by yourself.Or you could submit feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory) to ask improvement of ADF.